# Mathematica (v12.0) fails to Import NASACDF (Common Data Format)

Tags: import, windows

I was doing research about Mars using data from MAVEN spacecraft. The data used could be downloaded from https://lasp.colorado.edu/maven/sdc/public/data/sci/swe/l2/2017/06/.

When run

```
Import["C:\\...my PC dir...\\mvn_swe_l2_svy3d_20170601_v04_r07.cdf","Elements"]
```

The Mathematica returns

```
{"Annotations", "Data", "DataEncoding", "DataFormat", "Datasets", "Metadata"}
```

It seems fine. However, when I try to get more infomation such as "Annotations" or "Data" by

```
Import["C:\\...my PC dir...\\mvn_swe_l2_svy3d_20170601_v04_r07.cdf", "Annotations"]
```

or

```
Import["C:\\...my PC dir...\\mvn_swe_l2_svy3d_20170601_v04_r07.cdf", "Data"]
```

Mathematica returns `$Failed` and tell me it can't import data as NASACDF. This happened not only for SWE data. It seems that I can't Import any CDF files of MAVEN spacecraft. For example, when try to `Import` `Annotations` of SEP data from https://pds-ppi.igpp.ucla.edu/search/view/?f=yes&id=pds://PPI/maven.sep.calibrated/data/spec , Mathematica returns

```
can't use closed link LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0\SystemFiles\Converters\Binaries\Windows-x86-64\CDF.exe",1028,10]
```

and returns `EvaluatePacket[Null][[All, 2]]` when `Import` `Data` .

I was using Mathematica version 12.0 on windows 10. Help! Is there any workaround for me to read the data?

Comment: Both `Import["~/Downloads/mvn_swe_l2_svy3d_20170601_v04_r07.cdf", "Annotations"]` and `dat = Import["~/Downloads/mvn_swe_l2_svy3d_20170601_v04_r07.cdf", "Data"];` work for me on M12.0 macOS

Comment: That's weird. Does it depend on OS? @user6014